# Can I convert the sharp edges of a polygon easily to round edges?

Tags: python, polygon, geoprocessing, shapely

I use the python module "shapely" to make Polygons (like below). Can I convert the sharp edges of a polygon easily to round edges? Such that when I have unified some polygons I could issue a command like

```
make_round_edges(polygon, edge_rounding_radius)
```

?
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
polygon.buffer(10, join_style=1).buffer(-10.0, join_style=1)
```

A dilation, rounded (join_style=1), followed by an erosion, rounded. There's a diagram of a similar procedure at [The Shapely User Manual](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.buffer).

Comment: Dilating and then eroding works well for smoothing concave segments of the polygon, but leaves convex segments (extrusions) still sharp. Eroding and then dilating does the opposite. Therefore, I find that the best approach is to dilate by x, erode by 2*x, then dilate again by x. Here's an example demonstrating this: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kZGh7n7SYgX1VSeveENFu_Tg38aBPlvT?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4):

For rounding your convex angles, you can apply successively a negative then a positive buffer of the same radius. For the angles shown on your figure, you are thus applying the method on the blue polygons.

The buffer tool in shapely is described [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.buffer)

Comment: The url is 404.

Comment: thanks @Aaron, I've updated it