# Smoothing shapefiles using Python

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, python-3

The purple is the original polygon to be smoothed and I would like to smooth the polygons as the red line using Python.

I tried [simplify](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.simplify) but looks like I need a buffer and simplify the buffer. But I want to simplify the polygon directly. I am open to any other methods using Python.

```
import geopandas as gpd

d = gpd.read_file('poly.shp')
x = d.buffer(0.0001)

tolerance = 0.00005
simplified = x.simplify(tolerance, preserve_topology=True)
simplified.to_file('simplified.shp')
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need `simplify` for smoothing the polygon?

Comment: The simplify method is a [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer–Douglas–Peucker_algorithm) vertex removal algorithm. If you want a [Bend-Simplify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/how-simplify-line-works.htm) or something more exotic you might have to code it yourself.

Comment: maybe https://github.com/bmitto/bend-simplify

Comment: You don't need a buffer; the example you linked to is just using a buffer to create a polygon from a point. You can simplify your polygon/polyline directly.

Answer (score 7):

[This solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/93235/145962) worked for me. Just adjust the buffer amount to work with your units.

Solution copied here:

```
polygon.buffer(10, join_style=1).buffer(-10.0, join_style=1)
```