# Shapely adds more vertices to a polygon for smother snapping

Tags: shapely, snapping

I'm using `shapely` to snap together some polygons. The problem is that snapping in `shapley` only supports vertices to vertices snapping (i.e. a vertices from a polygon can only ever snapped to the vertices of another polygon) and not like other snapping tools where it is possible to snap to the whole geometry. This leads to undesirable effects as seen below.

First the polygons unsnapped:

[image]

and then snapped:

[image]

Since snapping to other geometric features (like for example in `postgis`) in `shapely` is not possible I thought if it is possible to introduce simply more vertices to the polygon so that snapping has more snapping targets. Is that possible and if so how?

my code currently looks like this:

```
input_gdf = input_gdf.copy()
for index, row in input_gdf.iterrows():
    # first we select polygons that are close to our 
    # row but not the geometry of the row itself
    temp_gdf = input_gdf[input_gdf.index != index]
    # this selects everything close by within buffer distance
    temp_gdf = temp_gdf[temp_gdf.geometry.intersects(row['geometry'].buffer(0.0001))]#
    # the closeby polygons get put together into one big multipolygon
    other_polys = MultiPolygon(temp_gdf['geometry'].to_list())

    # then we snap the geometry of row to the just created multipolygon
    # the snaped geometry overwrites the exisiting geometry in input_gdf
    input_gdf.loc[index,['geometry']]= snap(row['geometry'],other_polys,0.00003)
```

as you can see I iterate over the Geodataframe and select for every polygon the close polygons and then snap the current polygon to the vertices of the other polygons.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93213/can-i-convert-the-sharp-edges-of-a-polygon-easily-to-round-edges/93235#93235 Should create more vertices

Comment: I solve a couple of my problems with this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203058/why-is-shapelys-snapping-geo-snaps-not-working-as-expected by creating my own snapping and now polygon vertices snap to the geometry of other polygons. But still some polygons dont have enough vertices so this creates undesirable overlapping artifacts